# Convert NAD_1983_Mississippi_TM to Decimal Degrees in Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: arcgis-10.7

I have an excel file with coordinates in NAD_1983_Mississippi_TM that I need to have converted into Lat-Long decimal degrees.

I need a **new or updated spreadsheet** with NAD_1983_Mississippi_TM coordinates converted to decimal degrees.

Is there a way I can do this in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1 or in Excel without having to go back to each point one-by-one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in ArcGIS or Excel Spreadsheet?

Comment: Please provide an example - reproject in ArcGIS would be an option if shapefile/gdb.

Comment: If possible, I would like to have the coordinates converted in the Excel Spreadsheet. I don't necessarily need point features for the coordinates in ArcMap, but that would work for me if that's the quickest way.